# how to embedding fonts in indesign CS5 when exporting to pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-cs5, embedding

Please, I have question about how to exporting file from Indesign CS5 to PDF for Offset printing. In some cases there is a loss in the fonts (missing font) I used in the Indesign file. I've heard about "embedding" fonts in the pdf. Does this ensure that whatever font I choose will be rendered the same way always?  How do I do it? I know i can create outlines, but how if there's a lot pages?

I want to flatten all the pages to be sure that whatever font I choose will be rendered the same way every time.

So the question is: how can I embed fonts (create outlines) for all documents when exporting the file from Indesign CS5 to pdf (press quality)?